# JavaScript inside of Django for loop is not refreshing for every loop

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

So I have this code that checks if the value is a list, or a singe string. 
If it is a list, it creates and appends a img element into a div element every time Django for loop loops.
Else, it just creates one img element and apapends it into a div element.

But the problem is that, the data from the previous loop stays. Meaning that the JavaScript code, wasn't refreshing/washing every time it loops.
Is there a way to fix this? Thank you!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var index = 0
   let postImages = {{ postImages|safe }};  
 </script>
{% for info in post %}
  <a class="link_to_detail" href="{{ info.4 }}">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="images">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h3>{{ info.0 }}</h3>
        <p>{{ info.1 }}</p>
        <p><strong>{{ info.2 }}</strong></p>
        <p>{{ info.3|truncatechars:150 }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(typeof(postImages[index]))
    if (typeof(postImages[index]) == "object"){
        console.log(slides);
        document.querySelector('.images').classList.add('slides');
        for (let j = 0; j < postImages[index].length; j++){
          let img = document.createElement('img');
          let slides = document.querySelector('.slides')
          img.classList.add('image');
          img.src = postImages[index][j];
          console.log(postImages[index].length)
          slides.appendChild(img);
        }   
    }   else {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        let images = document.querySelector('.images');
        img.classList.add('image');
        img.setAttribute('src', postImages[index]);
        images.appendChild(img);
        console.log(images);
    }
    index++;
  </script>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Where is `postImages` initialized? What was your intent to involve js here?

Comment: Oops, my bad bro, just edited it.

Comment: The reason why I put the JS in there was so that I didn't have to put a for loop. And use the Django for loop instead.

Comment: Django template code and js code are processed in different time, so this won't work. Even if you make this Frankenstein work, this is still not a good idea in general. If you prefer js - use AJAX requests and do your JS stuff. `so that I didn't have to put a for loop` - you have two for-loops already here.

Comment: I see dude, Thanks for letting me know! :D